# Learning curve with dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a dataset, and I splitted it in percentages of 60, 20, 20. The 60% is for training, 20% is for testing and the rest is for validation (I made the split,because I need it).

I used the next code to split it (I think I found it in stackoverflow) and applied Naive Bayes classifier...

```
train_ratio = 0.60
validation_ratio = 0.20
test_ratio = 0.20

# train is now 60% of the entire data set
# the _junk suffix means that we drop that variable completely
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 1 - train_ratio)

# test is now 20% of the initial data set
# validation is now 20% of the initial data set
x_val, x_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(x_test, y_test, test_size=test_ratio/(test_ratio + validation_ratio)) 

print(x_train, x_val, x_test)



q=gnb.fit(x_train, y_train)

predict = gnb.predict(x_test)
print(predict)
print("Accuracy: ", accuracy_score(y_test, predict))
```

I tried use scikit-learn to make a learning curve, but according to [scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/learning_curve.html) the learning curve function gives the train_sizes, the train_scores and valid_scores.

This is kinda confusing, I'm new to scikit-learn, and I don't have a clue how to use make a learning curve with the each percentage of the data I splitted.

Does anyone knows how to use splitted data in scikit's learning curves?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need validation subset for `learning_curve`. train/test split is enough. you find necessary statistics on train via cv partitioner, and then use optimal params on test

Comment: I see, thank you very much.